Do I need to deposit my paycheck every month on the same day in order to get a UK tourist visa?
Should I be depositing my paycheck every month on the same date?
I usually do so after the 20th of every month. I read on a blog somewhere that for a UK tourist visa it's mandatory to do so.
I have a good travel history including Schengen countries most recently. I got refused a UK visa 2 years ago.

So its not mandatory for uk visa to deposit paycheck on the same date every month?

Depositing on the same day of the month is not essential, showing in your bank statement that you have a regular income which is enough to afford the travel is
Not all employers pay very regularly, mine can differ by two days now, in the past the payments were always on a Tuesday once a month so could differ by 6 days, the visa officers know about those differences and will not worry, especially if you are paid by check which you have to send to, or hand in at, the bank.
Paying it in every month is however important as it shows your income and that it is regular.
Having travelled to Schengen countries is a big positive but having been denied a UK visa in the past requires some attention.
Do you know why the visa was denied? If so, do you still have that same situation? In that case applying again might not be wise. If not sure asking a new question about it might help.

I was refused primarily since i answered no to the question ' do u have any other source of income or savings?' And i had a substancial amount of savings in my bank account since i stay jointly with my parents and work in a family business. I didnt mention these things in the cover letter. Also i made a mistake saying i rent a house. Can i enter the right answer this time which is no(share with parents)? I recently travelled to schengen countries.will it help?

Saying you rent a house when in fact you live with your parents is a very unusual/odd ‘mistake’
